# jQuery : How to detect difference between Nokia Lumia 830 and Microsoft Lumia 640?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova, phonegap

Currently developing hybrid mobile application which runs in windows phone. But currently facing issue with CSS for nokia lumia and microsoft lumia. I have 2 buttons at bottom. But for microsoft lumia, because of home button is on screen, user is not able to see bottom buttons. But for nokia lumia, home button is on device not on screen. I checked with CSS media query but both device have same height and width. Can anyone would suggest me how to resolve it? I need to find difference between both devices and put some media queries.

Thanks in advance.

1. Nokia Lumia 830 [image]
2. Microsoft Lumia 640 [image]

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/1.5.0/phonegap/device/device.name.html   ... Now if you got device name then add condition `if-else` and show corresponding button

Comment: Thanks @AlivetoDie .. but it's returning me as "null".

Comment: As per updated cordova-device-plugin, device.model will return you the name.

Comment: Make sure you check it after the `OnDeviceReady` event.